# p5.js sound library: how to add/remove p5. Phrases() from p5. Part()?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am working on a p5.js with sound library, and using p5 Phrase and p5 Part for making multiple sound files play at once.

I was able to `addPhrase()` but the `removePhrase()` function inside the `mousePressed` function does not work at all. 
How can I toggle between adding and removing phrases from the p5 Part, which would turn on/off the specific sound file?

```
var box, drum, myPart;
var drumPhrase;
var boxPhrase;
var boxPat = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0];
var drumPat = [0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0];

function preload() {
    box = loadSound('sound/noise.mp3');
    drum = loadSound('sound/drum1.wav');
}

function setup() {
    noStroke();
    fill(255);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    masterVolume(0.1);

    boxPhrase = new p5.Phrase('box', playBox, boxPat);
    drumPhrase = new p5.Phrase('drum', playDrum, drumPat);
    myPart = new p5.Part();

    myPart.addPhrase(boxPhrase);
    myPart.addPhrase(drumPhrase);

    myPart.setBPM(60);
    masterVolume(0.1);

    myPart.start();

}

function draw() {
    background(0);    
}

function playBox(time, playbackRate) {
    box.rate(playbackRate);
    box.play(time);
}

function playDrum(time, playbackRate) {
    drum.rate(playbackRate);
    drum.play(time);
}

function mousePressed() {
    myPart.removePhrase(box);

}
```

Comment: The reference says `removePhrase(phraseName)` where _phraseName_ is a string identifier. So in your case it should be `myPart.removePhrase('box');`

Comment: I have tried to do that already, but does not work as well...

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there is a bug in p5.sound so that p5.Part.removePhrase does not work.

Here's a fix: Add the following snippet at the end of your setup() function:

```
p5.Part.prototype.removePhrase = function (name) {
    for (var i in this.phrases) {
        if (this.phrases[i].name === name) {
            this.phrases.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
};
```

This replaces the buggy function with the actual working code.

I'll let the p5.js developers know so that the bug can be fixed in the official version.